# Why is my index missing documents with Thinking Sphinx?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I have a simple Thinking Sphinx index defined on my `Account` model:

```
define_index do
  indexes display_name
  indexes email_addresses.email_address

  has created_at
  set_property :delta => :datetime, :threshold => 2.minutes
end
```

(Ignore the delta for now; I'm generating the full index and searching `account_core`.)

But I'm getting some unexpected results:

```
>> Account.count
# => 885138

>> Account.search.total_entries
# => 260795

>> Account.search("lenny@paperlesspost.com")
# => []
```

However, on the command line, using the `search` utility, I'm able to find Lenny:

```
$ search -c /etc/sphinx/water.sphinx.conf -i account_core drew@example.com

index 'account_core': query 'drew@example.com.com ': returned 2 matches of 2 total in 0.759 sec

displaying matches:
1. document=3543432, weight=4, sphinx_internal_id=442101, sphinx_deleted=0, class_crc=0, created_at=Mon Apr 11 12:18:08 2011
2. document=5752816, weight=2, sphinx_internal_id=719552, sphinx_deleted=0, class_crc=0, created_at=Tue Dec 27 12:01:12 2011
```

Indeed those are Drew's account IDs.

Why am I not able to find Lenny when searching using Thinking Sphinx? Why is the `total_entries` number so much smaller than the total rows in the `accounts` table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the issue had to do with how Thinking Sphinx handles Single Table Inheritance. TS only returns records that have a `type` that corresponds to one of the parent class's subclasses. If `type` is `NULL`, the document isn't included in the search results. We had a lot of records in the `accounts` table with `type=NULL`. After fixing the data, searching now works as expected.

Thanks to roman3x in #sphinxsearch for pointing me to this.